# App builds for Simulator, but not for 'Generic iOS Device'

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am experimenting with pulling data from the internet for my app, and everything works as it should when the app is run in the iOS Simulator or on my own device.

The frameworks I'm using are [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/), [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) and [GzipSwift](https://github.com/1024jp/GzipSwift); I cloned the Github repo of the `Gzip` framework, build it myself, dragged the .framework into my project navigator and linked it up (added the framework to *Link Binary with Libraries* under *Build Phases*).

Now, when I build the code for any specific device, it compiles and runs just fine, but when I select 'Generic iOS Device' as the target, the build process fails and tells me that it couldn't find the methods I used from the Gzip framework.

I am quite certain I missed some setting or didn't import the framework correctly, but I have no clue on how to fix this.

Any ideas?

Comment: and you are talking about cmd + b, just normal build?

Comment: if you make an custom framework you can make a fat library , you can see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977145/3992606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you build the framework only with the simulator architecture instead of building it for all architectures (arm64).

Comment: You are probably right; I assume this would've solved my problem as well. In the end, I just compiled the framwork using Carthage and so far everything seems to work...