# Xcode - Can run app on simulator but not on device - error: Failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

I am trying to install my AR app onto my device. If I build it onto the simulator it installs but obviously I can't test it as its not possible to run AR on simulator.

The problem is that when I try to run it on my device I get this error

> **error: Failed with exit code 1**

The error above this is

> Codesigning /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARanalytix-efmsytiskdgeajgnizwosccslwsj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARanalytix.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
>   /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 239D4B0E67A04154536E45B1893911C2673A85F5 --verbose /Users/samosborne/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARanalytix-efmsytiskdgeajgnizwosccslwsj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARanalytix.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
>   /Users/samosborne/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARanalytix-efmsytiskdgeajgnizwosccslwsj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARanalytix.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

I have tried cleaning my project, downloading certificates again, and also followed the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-high-sierra-xcode-resource-fork-finder-information) but cant get it to work.

Any help would be great as I am out of ideas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like a similar question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023639/xcode-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-errsecinternalcomponen

Comment: @totiG I had a look at this feed and tried unlocking my keychain and allowed access on my certificates but that doesn't seem to solve anything

Comment: you can make a fat library , you can see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977145/3992606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried restarting my Mac and also deleted the certificates from my keychain. I then changed my bundle identifier name and it all seemed to work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of reasons why it doesn't run.

1) You need a download a develop provisioning profile, if you are using a production certificate it will not run.

2) Be sure from Apple portal to include you device UDID and download a new  development provisioning profile including your device.

3) From the project plist be sure to select the correct provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

Did you Restart Mac and iOS Device. Hope this will work

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.